# Php - Как вывести информации из txt файла?

Tags: php

Php - Как вывести информации из txt файла?

Допустим есть файл с разными запросами
Например: keywords.txt
В файле в каждой новой строке лежит ключевик
Пример:

```
love

love quotes

love poems

love culture

love calculator

love and hip hop atlanta

love songs

lovenox

love tester

loveland reporter herald

lovelace

loves truck stop
```

Ключевики разной длины и почти все спробелами, есть и без пробелов.
Вопрос: Как вывести запросы из файла в автоматическом режиме эти ключевики? Ключевики должны браться через 30 минут новые...
То есть прошло 30 минут, спустились на 5 строк, берем следующие и так до конца. Если закончились идем в начало строки и повторяем процедуру.
Если есть пробелы, то заменяем их на (-)

```
Вывод ключевиков из файла должен быть такого рода:

<a href="mydomen.com/search.php?jjj=love" title="love">love</a>

<a href="mydomen.com/search.php?jjj=love-quotes" title="love quotes">love quotes</a>
<a href="mydomen.com/search.php?jjj=love-poems" title="love poems">love poems</a>
```

Comment: почему не хотите использовать базу данных для этого?

Comment: Не могли бы вы помочь мне в этом? Я просто не силен в php. Могу только немного подправить или дописать немного...
А базу данных не желательно для этого...
Лучше скрипт, если можно пожалуйста...

Answer (score 1):

Возьму на себя ответственность:

```
<?php
$data = file('keys.txt');   // сами кейворды
$seek = file('count.ini');  // указатель
$step = 5;                  // сколько выводить

$i= 0;
$out = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $val) { // убираем пробелы и лишние символы, пустые строки
    $tmp = trim($val);
    if (!empty($tmp)) { $out[$i] = str_replace(' ', '-', $tmp); $i++; }
}

if ($step > count($out)) { // вдруг ключей меньше чем шаг с которым выводить
    foreach ($out as $key => $val) {
        echo $val, '<br />';
    } die();
}

if ($seek[0] >= count($out)) $seek[0] = 0; // вдруг редактировали ключи
                                           // а записалась старая позиция в файле
// var_dump($out);

for ($k=0; $k<$step; $k++) { // сам вывод
    echo $out[$seek[0]], '<br />';
    $seek[0]++; if ($seek[0] == count($out)) $seek[0] = 0;
}

file_put_contents('count.ini', $seek[0]); // запишем позицию с которой потом начать
?>
```

Перед запуском создайте файлы:

- count.ini - просто с одной строчкой и одним символом ноль ('0')
- keys.txt - тут вставьте кейворды
- сохранить скрипт скажем в файл do.php и поставьте крон задачу раз в 30 минут
- как сделать крон задачу вам подскажут в службе поддержки вашего сервера

Демка тут: http://ul.vv.si/kwrd/do.php

На элегантность кода не претендую, может кто подскажет как сделать проще)

Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо, скрипт работает, но не совсем правильно.
Крон тут не играет - так как перейдя по вашей ссылке http://ul.vv.si/kwrd/do.php, достаточно просто обновить и ключи меняются... даже без крона.